# x11 window delay on OSX

Tags: macos, x11, osx-elcapitan, xquartz

I have a newer generation macbook pro. I have El Capitan installed with the latest X11 release from xquartz. Whenever I try to open up a X11 window, such as just running xclock, it takes about 15 seconds to get the window. If I do the same thing on my work laptop, which has an identical version of OS X and X11, it takes a fraction of a second. I can't figure out what is going on. Does anyone have some suggestions of what the problem could be, or how to diagnose such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out that macports had its own X11, and didn't rely on XQuartz. I uninstalled XQuartz, and just used the macports xorg.server for my X11. Still don't know why having both works fine on my work laptop but not on my personal laptop. Oh well...problem fixed.